# Deployment Error: "Invalid parameter value" on one of my custom profiles during Dev > Dev deployment

Tags: deployment, error, parameters, custom-profile

> I am deploying a brand new Custom Object and all associated Custom Fields from one Dev environment to another Dev environment. I'm receiving the "**Invalid parameter value**" error on one of my custom profiles during the
>   validation for deployment.

**Screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot of Invalid parameter value error]

---

**I've read this StackExchange post** suggesting that I need to create the Profile manually in my receiving org first (do my own clone) prior to validating/deploying:
[Invalid parameter type error while deploying custom profile](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/31668/invalid-parameter-type-error-while-deploying-custom-profile)

> However, the profile in question **already exists** in the receiving org
>   and the sending org.

---

**I also know that Salesforce had a Known Issue** regarding validate/deploy of profiles with "View All Data" settings, but this was resolved in Winter '16 based on their Known Issue:
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4OvAAK

---

Due to the generic nature of the error, I am unsure exactly where to begin in debugging it farther. As I am deploying a brand new object, I don't really want to resort to excluding my profile from the ChangeSet and needing to go manually fix all profile CRUD and field level security in the receiving org.

***It may be worth noting that the originating org is on Summer '16, and the receiving org has been upgraded to the Winter '17 preview.***

> **Question:** Does the difference in Salesforce releases between orgs
>   have anything to do with this problem? Is there anything else that I can do (other than excluding my profile(s)) to resolve this problem without engaging Salesforce support?

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you put into formatting. Thanks.

Comment: I have had this happen before IIRC when the sending org was on a newer release. It was resolved when the receiving org was upgraded to the new release. It does not help you now though.

Comment: Added screenshot as requested @AdrianLarson, tho I don't know if it will help because I'm learning more towards thinking the same thing as Eric. It might be because of difference in version

Comment: That sucks. Is the `Profile` your only component? If not, can you try reducing your `Change Set` down to just that and seeing if it will go through.

Comment: No there are about 80 components, a new custom object, all related custom fields of that object, 2 apex classes/2 test classes, 2 triggers, etc. Basically everything related to that new object. I'll try that - and if that doesn't work I guess I'll have to push it to this org without the profile and fix it on the receiving end. Not ideal but we do what we must!

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same issue (new custom object, 'invalid parameter value' deployment error when including a custom profile). However both origin and target sandboxes are on the same release (Summer '17). :<(

I see a Known Issue [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000001CV0QAM&title=changeset-validation-of-the-profile-which-is-cloned-from-sysadmin-and-doesn-t-have-modify-all-data-fails) about this error if a profile is cloned from System Administrator but has Modify All permission removed. Recently updated so there still seems to be some wonkiness in this general area.